# Severity 016 Backup virtual device fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My backup on one of my servers is failing once a week.  This is the alert I'm getting:

> DESCRIPTION:  BackupVirtualDeviceFile::PrepareToFreeze:  failure on
>   backup device '{DE47BFA0-E5AD-46DD-868C-F374CB5C2EF7}1'. Operating
>   system error 995(The I/O operation has been aborted because of either
>   a thread exit or an application request.).

I have no idea where to start to figure out why it's fialing, and google hasn't helped me much.

If I look at the application error log on the server, I have a SQLVDI error:

> SQLVDI: Loc=SignalAbort. Desc=Client initiates abort. ErrorCode=(0).
>   Process=2028. Thread=2452. Client. Instance=.
>   VD=Global{DE47BFA0-E5AD-46DD-868C-F374CB5C2EF7}1_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.

After that I have a MSSQLSERVER error:

> BackupVirtualDeviceFile::PrepareToFreeze:  failure on backup device
>   '{DE47BFA0-E5AD-46DD-868C-F374CB5C2EF7}1'. Operating system error
>   995(The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit
>   or an application request.).

And a SQLWriter backup:

> Sqllib error: OLEDB Error encountered calling ICommandText::Execute.
>   hr = 0x80040e14. SQLSTATE: 42000, Native Error: 3013 Error state: 1,
>   Severity: 16 Source: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 Error
>   message: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. SQLSTATE: 42000,
>   Native Error: 3271 Error state: 1, Severity: 16 Source: Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0 Error message: A nonrecoverable I/O error
>   occurred on file "{DE47BFA0-E5AD-46DD-868C-F374CB5C2EF7}1:" 995(The
>   I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an
>   application request.).

How can I figure out what's causing this failure?

Comment: Is it for all databases? Or just one? Does the operation fail at the same time each week? Does it work during other times? What else is running at the same time the backup fails?

Comment: @Cougar9000 yes, all databases.  yes, it works at toher times, but seems to always fail on sundays.

Comment: How are you executing the backups?

Comment: Is there any external SAN backup/snapshot tool doing its work at the same time?

Comment: @Cougar9000 scheduled sql server maintenance plan.

Comment: Check these links .. http://troubleshootingsql.com/2011/02/09/troubleshooting-that-darn-backup-error/ ; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/04/28/is-sqlvdi-dll-functioning-properly.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/04/28/informational-shedding-light-on-vss-vdi-backups-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: One more thing to check, are your databases actually being backed up successfully? And is this error potentially coming from the VSS/Snapshot backup failing? None of those error msg's say SQL Server failed to backup <yourDBname> database

Comment: @Cougar9000 i didn't include it, but there were messages in the app log that explicitly stated "backup of database x failed".

Comment: @DForck42: In your maintenance plan, what is the destination for your database backups?